# Introduction of a hydro/aquaponics Stack Exchange section

Tags: discussion, site-proposal

I wanted to ask if it would make sense to create a *hydroponics* specific Stack Exchange site. This could be extended to (automated) *farming* in general. The idea behind it is that there is a large amount of accumulated knowledge by people active in this area and might have the potential to become a vibrant community.

The questions in this domain may range from the pure growing aspect of plants, all the way to autonomous monitoring systems that employ robotics and integrated software solutions. There are also several different approaches to hydroponics, which would result in a range of different questions.

Comment: Better ask in [Area 51 Discussions](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/), where people more familiar with site proposal are active.

Comment: @bummi I don't think this is a duplicate. That other question is about _how_ to create a new SE site. This question, IMO, is asking if there is enough interest in a specific subject.

Comment: @S.L.Barth I would believe this is how sites get "generated" on Area51, by proposing, test run and getting enough people with enough interest.

Comment: Added a line in the duplicate to point users to the Discussion Zone.

Comment: @S.L.Barth well, it's off topic here. Technically better close reason is "This question pertains only to a specific site" (Area 51 in this case) but not worth reopening for that.

Comment: It's always 4:20 somewhere

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. The best fit probably is https://gardening.stackexchange.com/